# Exclude interface implementation members through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I have the following Interface, and implementation:

```
public interface INew
{
    string TestString { get; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : INew
{
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public string TestString
    {
        get { return "This is a test string"; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to reflect out the `OrderNo` part of the `PurchaseOrder` object, using the following code:

```
var props = p.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}
```

My output is returning the `TestString` property also.  I have searched for ways to exclude implemented interface members but can only find items to include it.  Can anybody show me how i can exclude such items?

Comment: You could use the [Type.GetInterfaceMap Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) i think. But probably you have to be careful with hierarchies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using the GetInterfaceMap Method:

```
var interfaceMethods = typeof(PurchaseOrder)
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Select(x => typeof(PurchaseOrder).GetInterfaceMap(x))
    .SelectMany(x => x.TargetMethods).ToArray();

var propsNotFromInterface= typeof(PurchaseOrder)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
    .Where(x => !x.GetAccessors(true).Any(y => interfaceMethods.Contains(y))).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(propsNotFromInterface.Length);
```

You can refactor this into a generic method very easily.

Comment: `(BindingFlags)62`?

Comment: Ops, its a debugging shortcut i use, its for `Public | NonPublic | Instance | Static`

Comment: Works perfectly for me, even with multiple interfaces implemented!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try excluding properties that defined in `INew` like:

```
PurchaseOrder p = new PurchaseOrder();
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
PropertyInfo[] iNewPropertyInfos = typeof(INew).GetProperties(bindingFlags);
var props = p.GetType().GetProperties(bindingFlags).Where(x => iNewPropertyInfos.All(y => y.ToString() != x.ToString()));
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
}
```

**Update.**

More generic approach would be moving that logic into generic function:

```
private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesExcept<T>(object p)
{
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
    PropertyInfo[] iNewPropertyInfos = typeof (T).GetProperties(bindingFlags);
    return p.GetType().GetProperties(bindingFlags).Where(x => iNewPropertyInfos.All(y => y.ToString() != x.ToString()));
}
```

And usage:

```
PurchaseOrder p = new PurchaseOrder();
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesExcept = GetPropertiesExcept<INew>(p);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work however i was hoping for a more generic approach - I have several interfaces.  However for now it will move me forward!

Comment: Thanks for the update, however if i have a class that implements multiple interfaces implemented explicitly they are still present (fully qualified name).